# Bash help deleting nested directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Ok this may sound bizarre but I have a directory /PDB/ that I want to scan for all contained directories. All of these directories contain several files and a subdirectory name /pockets/ that may or may not be empty. I want to delete every parent directory and all its contents that contains an empty /pockets/ subdirectory. So far I have this code:

```
cd /PDB/
for D in */
do
   find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rm -r $D +
done
```

This does not currently execute, giving the error 
find: missing argument to '-exec'

Earlier I was using {} instead of $D but that only deleted the empty subdirectory.

Comment: `+` is only valid when `{}` is the argument *immediately* preceding it.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use `find` here at all. Consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ - NOT /bin/sh; using bash-only features here

shopt -s nullglob           # if no matches exist, expand to an empty list
for d in /PDB/*; do         # iterate over subdirectories
  set -- "$d"/pockets/*     # set argument list to contents of pockets/ subdirectory
  (( "$#" )) && continue      # if the glob matched anything, we aren't empty
  rm -rf -- "${d%/pockets/}"  # if we *are* empty, delete the parent directory
done
```

...or, if you *really* want to use `find`:

```
find /PDB -type d -name pockets -empty -exec bash -c '
  for arg; do
    rm -rf -- "${arg%/*}"
  done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: Ok this did the job! Thank you! Are there any particular resources you would recommend for learning the more nitty gritty bash stuff like what you used in the first script?

Comment: The Wooledge [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) (and other associated pages -- f/e [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)) are really great resources; so is the [bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org).